# Local DNS server without specify domain name

Tags: domain-name-system

I am hosting a local DNS server on a Synology with domain name *example.com*

My configuration is the most basic possible:

```
example.com          NS   ns.example.com
ns.example.com       NS   8.8.8.8
server1.example.com   A    192.168.0.10
```

Currently to access *server1*, my users have to write *http://server1.example.com* or `ping server1.example.com`

What kind of configuration should I do in my DNS to access by this way *http://server1* or ping *server1* without having to specify the domain name?

Comment: Windows? Linux? Which DNS software? What's the configuration? What did you try to do? Please edit your question, like this it's very low quality.

Comment: done, but my configuration is pretty basic
i'm using the DNS package from Synology, but i supposed that every every DNS server work by the same way ?

Answer (score 5):

You don't add this to the DNS server. Instead, this is configured as "Local search domains" in the *clients* DNS config - you just add `example.com` to this list and the OS will add this to the name search if just searching for `server1` yields no results.

This can also be done via DHCP (in the `domain-name` option).